# WordPress is off-topic

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions about WordPress on Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/920/questions-about-wordpress-on-super-user)

I see a number of superuser.com WordPress threads closed as "closed as off-topic".

In the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) I see "websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress".

That FAQ entry should be updated to "WordPress.com". WordPress is ambiguous and also refers to the CMS software downloaded from [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/)

Further, "Web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is "designer", ask on Doctype." should be updated to include "Web Design/Hosting/CMS" as listed at "[Where can I ask questions that aren’t Super User questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions)"

Comment: There does appear to be a need for some clarification.

Comment: yes, it is.  no, it's not ambiguous: wordpress is offtopic.  both of them: the service and the web application.  see the duplicate link, and the [Web Applications site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications) on Area51.

Comment: i'm not sure what you're asking about the [where-to-ask-questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions) link; the body of that question post already mentions the wording you seem to want to use.  maybe post a comment on the question or answer that you think needs to be updated?